# Stop Resharper from spamming output window

Tags: resharper

Anyone know where I can change the settings to stop resharper from outputting these messages to the output window whle debugging?

```
'JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunner.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Users\\assembly\..\1b8b40\98a8d8_9211cd01\.DLL', Symbols loaded.
```

Comment: That looks a lot like the messages that the debugger would have written to the output window.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off Module Load Messages found here:

```
Debug Menu/Options and Settings/Output Window/Module Load Messages
```